# Find the max length of list inside another list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I need to get the max lenght of a list INSIDE another list, which in turn is insside a dictionary.

Let's say I have:

```
x={
'a':[[1],[1,2,3],[1],[1]],
'b':[[1],[1,2],[1],[1]],
'c':[[1],[1,2],[1],[1]]
}
```

All I need is to get `3` (max lenght according to second list of 'a').

So far I've been searching for similar approaches but I only could find iteration on the first level of lists and I just get `4` (lenght of 'a','b' and 'c' values: 4 lists) which is NOT what I'm looking for.

So far I have:

```
x={
'a':[[1],[1,2,3],[1],[1]],
'b':[[1],[1],[1],[1]],
'c':[[1],[1],[1],[1]]
}

maxlist=len(x[[k for k in x.keys() if x[k]==max(x.values(),key=len)][0]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the keys of the dictionary and instead, use a double `max`:

```
x = {'a': [[1], [1, 2, 3], [1], [1]], 'c': [[1], [1, 2], [1], [1]], 'b': [[1], [1, 2], [1], [1]]}
result = max(max(map(len, i)) for i in x.values())
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: That works perfectly, I'll definitely will practice with double max! Thank you very much, you're a life saver!

Comment: @Victor Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to flatten.

```
>>> counts = [len(b) for a in x.values() for b in a]
[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

>>> max(counts)
3
```

Or for optimal performance, use a generator:

```
max(len(b) for a in x.values() for b in a)
```

Comment: With this method, I'd advise you use a generator comprehension instead of building a list. For a dictionary with a large number of sublists, list creation can be expensive.

Comment: awesome! i'll take it into account. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

res = max(map(len, chain.from_iterable(x.values())))

# 3
```